# How to add a mailto newline that works on most email browser clients

Tags: javascript, html, email, mailto

I'm trying to create a mailto address that sends three string values and I need to have them displayed on three different lines.

For testing purposes I've used Office, Gmail, Yahoo and IBM Verse.

First, I've tried using **%0D%0A** and **\r\n** as line breaks. This worked on Office and Gmail but did not work on Yahoo or IBM Verse.

Second, I've tried using **`<br>`** but this worked only for IBM Verse. Gmail didn't interpret my HTML and just displayed it as plain text and Yahoo just ignored it (neither displaying text or adding a newline).

I've tried adding both of them covering most clients I've tested on but I have no way to hide the HTML that Gmail does not display. Also, I've yet to find a way to add a newline that works on Yahoo.

```
mailto:?subject=This%20is%20a%20Test&body=%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3EThis%20is%20the%20Body%20first%20line%20%3Cbr%3E%20%0A%0D%0A%20second%3Cbr%3E%20%0A%0D%0A%20%20This%20is%20the%20third%20line%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E
```

Any ideas on how I can improve the link?

Comment: Try to use `\r\n`

Comment: I've tried and it works exactly like %0D%0A. I'll update the question to add this remark, thanks!

Comment: I think, its a security reason, why gmail dont allow this (i think) - XSS protection(?)